# Where do I get proof of intended travel for German visa?

Tags: tickets, schengen-visas

I have been asked to submit my passport for stamping for a German national visa. One of the required documents is listed as *Proof of your intended travel date (e.g. copy of flight reservation, flight ticket is not required)*.

Where do I get this? I understand that I don't have to book and pay for a ticket. but what is the valid alternative to this?

Comment: Well, when and how do you intend to travel? And where are you going? Give us some information to help you answer ([edit] your question)

Comment: I honestly don't understand your problem. Are the terms 'proof' and 'e.g.' somehow not clear to you? Maybe English Learners would be a better place to ask then... 
Of course it's not required for you to get to Germany via airplane, but you need to get there somehow, stay somewhere, and get out somehow...

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments/questions. Closing as unclear until they do.